# Upgrading Nhibernate unable to save large string in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, oracle, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Upgrading NHibernate version from **2.1.2.4000** to **3.3.1.4000** in our dot net application. It stores string of almost 9000 characters in previous version but in 3.3.1.4000 it gives error.

In SQL Server type is **ntext** & in Oracle it is **nclob**
And in hbm file we are using

```
<property name="Value" column ="SettingValue" type="AnsiString"/>
```

Above code works for oracle in both versions but not in sql server.
I tried length="10000" & few other option but no use.

Comment: I dont know the answer to your question but you should not be using ntext in sql server. That datatype has been deprecated since 2005. You should instead be using nvarchar(max).

Comment: @SeanLange Use as it is legacy application, but currently we need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL server mapping type is `type="StringClob"`

```
<property name="Value" column ="SettingValue" type="StringClob" />
```